# Kaplan-Meier with known censor distribution

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

I would like to know if you can do better than Kaplan-Meier when you know the censor distribution. I searched google but I could not find anything.

This problem seems to be quite natural/useful when you are doing hypothesis testing and your Null includes information about the censor distribution.

Thanks

Comment: When you refer to the "censor distribution" are you referring to censoring without failure?

Comment: @Todd I'm not quite sure what do you mean with censoring without failure, but what I do mean is the classic, say, 'right censor model'.  Your data consist in several independent observations of $X = min(T,C)$ and $\delta = 1_{\{X = T\}}$, where $T$ and $C$ are independent. You want to estimate the distribution of $T$ and you know the distribution of $C$

Comment: In theory and ideally the failure probability is the same for observed and censored units. If you knew the censoring distribution, you would know the failure probability of observed units?